# Distributed multiprocessing pool in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, distributed-computing, pathos

I have an existing bit of Python code that runs in parallel across the cores in my machine. The job it completing is basically open an input file, read the contents, perform some fairly heavy maths, write the results to an output a file, take the next file in the for loop and do it again. To make this parallel across many cores I make use of the `Pool` function in the `multiprocessing` library. As a quick example:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

data = (
['a', '2'], ['b', '4'], ['c', '6'], ['d', '8'],
['e', '1'], ['f', '3'], ['g', '5'], ['h', '7']
)

def mp_worker((inputs, the_time)):
    print " Processs %s\tWaiting %s seconds" % (inputs, the_time)
    time.sleep(int(the_time))
    print " Process %s\tDONE" % inputs

def mp_handler():
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(8)
    p.map(mp_worker, data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp_handler()
```

This example is just used to show how I've implemented the `multiprocessing.Pool` function across 8 cores. In essence the `mp_worker` function in my code is much more complex but you get my drift.

I've come to realise that the network I'm working on has several machines sitting idle for 99% of their time. I therefore wondered if there is a way to make use of their cores as well as my local cores in this code.

In pseudo code the code could become something like:

```
def mp_handler():
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(servers=['local host', 192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.2], ncores=[8,8,4])
    p.map(mp_worker, data)
```

Where I can now specify both my local machine and other IP addresses as severs together with the number of cores I'd like to use on each machine.

Since the other machines on my network are owned by me and are not internet connected, I'm not fussed about using SSH for security purposes.

Googling around I've noticed that the `pathos` and `scoop` libraries may be able to help me with this. It looks like `pathos` has very similar commands to the `multiprocessing` library which really appeals to me. However, in both cases I can't find a simple example showing me how to convert my local parallel job into a distributed parallel job. I'm keen to stay as close to the Pool/map functionality of the `multiprocessing` library as possible.

Any help or examples would be much appreciated!

Comment: check out https://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing

Answer (score 3):

The example from `pathos` is pretty much like your pseudo-code.

```
from pathos.parallel import stats
from pathos.parallel import ParallelPool as Pool
pool = Pool()

def host(id):
    import socket
    import time
    time.sleep(1.0)
    return "Rank: %d -- %s" % (id, socket.gethostname())


print "Evaluate 10 items on 2 cpus"
pool.ncpus = 2
pool.servers = ('localhost:5653',)
res5 = pool.map(host, range(10))
print pool
print '\n'.join(res5)
print stats()
print ''
```

Above, you could have set `ncpus` and `servers` as keywords when initializing the `Pool` instance.

The results look like this:

```
Evaluate 10 items on 2 cpus
<pool ParallelPool(ncpus=2, servers=('localhost:5653',))>
Rank: 0 -- hilbert.local
Rank: 1 -- hilbert.local
Rank: 2 -- hilbert.local
Rank: 3 -- hilbert.local
Rank: 4 -- hilbert.local
Rank: 5 -- hilbert.local
Rank: 6 -- hilbert.local
Rank: 7 -- hilbert.local
Rank: 8 -- hilbert.local
Rank: 9 -- hilbert.local
Job execution statistics:
 job count | % of all jobs | job time sum | time per job | job server
        10 |        100.00 |      10.0459 |     1.004588 | local
Time elapsed since server creation 5.0402431488
0 active tasks, 2 cores
```

If you have more than one server, with potentially remote servers, you just need to add more entries to the `servers` tuple.  So that's not a perfect example, as it doesn't show exactly how to get servers going on another machine.  However, it is a good example, if you ever do plan to use a ssh `tunnel`, you should know that you don't point `pathos` at the remote machine, but you point instead at `localhost` with the tunneled port… and that connects to the remote machine.

Since `pathos` uses `ppft` (which is a fork of `pp`), you can look at examples from `pp` on how to set up a remote server. Basically, you can do something like this with a shell script:

```
for i in $nodes
do
    ssh -f $i /home/username/bin/ppserver.py -p $portnum -w 2 -t 30 &
done
```

Here the loop is over the nodes received (nodes).  For each node, a `ssh -f` command is used to start a `ppserver` with a specified port (-p), two workers (-w), and timeout after 30 seconds of idle (-t). See the `pp` documentation (http://www.parallelpython.com/content/view/15/30). With `pathos`, you only really need to start a `ppserver` and specify the port to make it work.  Then, you'd add the hostname and port to the `server` tuple in the first block of code.

However, if you are adverse to setting up things manually, `pathos` does provide scripts that set up a `tunnel` and also a `ppserver`.  Using a script is a little less flexible than doing so manually, and a bit more difficult to diagnose when things go wrong… but nonetheless… see the scripts here: https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos/tree/master/scripts.

Comment: A few more things: (1) I'm the `pathos` author, (2) distributed computing is fairly fragile, so be forewarned that things will fail at some point, and leave a mess to clean up, (3) the cost of the function you are going to distribute has to be higher than the cost of making the connection to the distributed cluster, starting up a python instance, and tunneling over the objects, and (4) you have to have the same version of `ppft` installed on all machines or you get an error.